# Chai as promised not waiting for promise to be fulfilled

Tags: javascript, promise, mocha.js, chai, chai-as-promised

An output of my console. Note that the console logs are out of order (1,3,4,2 instead of 1,2,3,4)

[image: ![enter image description here]

Code here

```
  it('can store file', () => {
    console.log('1) file storage start')
    return filestore.store.q(file).then(() => {
      console.log('2) file storage done')
    }).should.eventually.be.fullfilled
  })

  describe('block number', () => {

    beforeEach(() => {
      console.log('3) check blockNumber')
      return web3.Q.all([
        web3.eth.getBlockNumber.q().then((_blockNumber) => {
          blockNumber = _blockNumber
        }),
        web3.eth.getMining.q().then((isMining) => {
        })
      ])
    })

    it('can retreive files block number', () => {
      console.log('4) retreive')
      return filestore.getBlockNumber.q(fileHash).should.eventually.bignumber.equal(blockNumber)
    })

  })
```

Comment: What's the code of `filestore.store.q`? I've used Chai-as-Promised extensively. Never had a problem with it.

Comment: It would take a lot of work to add that code here in a meaningful way (its a ver complicated function). However its definetetly returning a proper promise as evident by 1) the then function fires and 2) chai-as-promised accepts it as fulfilled

Comment: What is `.bignumber`?

Comment: its from chai-bignumber

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a stupid typo. I typed `fullfilled` instead of `fulfilled`

Answer (score -1):

I suspect you are getting a side-effect from Chai. Try testing without it first, for example:

```
const assert = require('assert');

it('can store file', () => {
    console.log('1) file storage start')
    return filestore.store.q(file).then(() => {
      // Promise should have fulfilled. Nothing more to do.
      // Using should and chai after this is probably causing the problem.
      // But you should really add some sort of assertion here to
      // be able to detect regressions.
      console.log('2) file storage done')
    });
  });

  describe('block number', () => {
    let blockNumber;

    beforeEach(() => {
      console.log('3) check blockNumber')
      return web3.Q.all([
        web3.eth.getBlockNumber.q().then((_blockNumber) => {
          blockNumber = _blockNumber
        }),
        web3.eth.getMining.q().then((isMining) => {
        })
      ])
    })

    it('can retreive files block number', () => {
      console.log('4) retreive')
      return filestore.getBlockNumber.q(fileHash)
        .then((result) => {
          // I'm not sure if assert.equal will work with big numbers.
          // You might need a different comparator here.
          assert.equal(result, blockNumber, 'should equal the blocknumber));
        });
    });
  });
```

Mocha knows how to handle a returned Promise so there's really no need for Chai. It's unnecessary sugar.